# "rosdep update" error in Kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all;

I am installing Ros Kinetic in a new machine with Ubuntu 16.04.
Everything goes fine, until I try to do a "rosdep update" command.
I obtain the following errors repetedly:

```
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml]:
    <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml]:
    <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml]:
    <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml]:
    <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
    <urlopen error no host given>
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
ERROR: error loading sources list:
    <urlopen error <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml)>
```

I have already read the related questions and answers related to this issue, but none of them fully applies to my problem.

EDIT (links to questions and answers):

https://answers.ros.org/question/162996/cannot-update-rosdep/

https://answers.ros.org/question/277395/rosdep-update-the-read-operation-timed-out/

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/386

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/9721

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/576

http://blog.csdn.net/gddxz_zhouhao/article/details/72861266

The rosdep update output that I am obtaining is:

```
a4blue@a4blue-HP-EliteDesk-800-G3-TWR:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d

-------------------

url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml'

----------------

ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml]:
    <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml)

-------------------

url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml'

----------------

ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml]:
    <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml)

------------------

url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml'

----------------

ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml]:
    <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml)

-------------------

url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml'

----------------

ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml]:
    <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml]:
    Failed to download target platform data for gbpdistro:
    <urlopen error no host given>
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
ERROR: error loading sources list:
    <urlopen error <urlopen error no host given> (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml)>
a4blue@a4blue-HP-EliteDesk-800-G3-TWR:~$
```

Can anyone give a clue about this issue?

Thank you all very much in advance,
Best,

Alberto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284683/%22rosdep-update%22-error-in-kinetic/) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:
Can you link us to the Q&As you've already looked at? Just to avoid forum members from suggesting the same solutions.

You can use the `q#nnnnnn` format to link to questions, don't need to copy-paste the complete url.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:
Probably start with the regular things to check:

- `ping github.com` works?
- are you behind a (company) firewall or proxy server?
- can you `wget` any of those URLs?
- is your computers clock and date set correctly?

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2018-03-07**:
Everything is ok. ping works, I can do wget, clock and date correct. In the same company network, I have installed other previous versions of ROS without problems.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:\

> urlopen error no host given

this seems to suggest that there is no host part in the url passed to `urlopen`. If you can, it would probably be easiest to instrument the `rosdep` code to get it to print whatever URL it is about to pass to `urllib` and see whether something is wrong there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:\

> I have installed other previous versions of ROS without problems.

that doesn't necessarily mean that something couldn't have changed that now prevents you from doing the same of course.

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2018-03-07**:
I know...I am going to try to install Kinetic in another machine just to check. How can I make rosdep to print the information you a referring to?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:\

> I am going to try to install Kinetic in another machine just to check

that might be a bit drastic. What about installing Docker on a machine (if it doesn't already have it) and then using the `ros:kinetic` image see if `rosdep` wants to play nice? You could even do that on your own machine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-07**:\

> How can I make rosdep to print the information you a referring to?

by editing the sources. I don't think there is a built-in facility for this unfortunately.

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2018-03-08**:
I have installed Kinetic in a Virtualbox clean image of  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and everything goes perfect. The machine with Virtualbox is in the same LAN, so installation under same conditions. Tha PC that fails has also installed freeling, stardog and xampp. Could affect?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
[this](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/blob/94918bd59c7baa4641d38dd3da17a6b4b21e0119/src/rosdep2/sources_list.py#L303) is where the download is attempted. Searching for the error (no host given) turns up a lot of results where spurious `\n` characters at the end of URLs made `urllib` ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
.. fail. It's a long shot, but can you check that the files in `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d` are ok? No windows line-endings fi?

You could add something like:

```
print ("\n\n-------------------\n\nurl: '{}'\n\n----------------\n\n".format(url))
```

right above the line I linked to see ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
.. what URL `rosdep` is really trying to download.

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2018-03-08**:
there is only one file. Seems ok, line endings correct.
I have modified the file and the urls seem also ok. I paste the output in the following link:
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rQWJd1wkvph1jJAlKuUM_zdWgGYdcbla]

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
Please *edit* your original question. Comments are not suited for this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
One thing to check could be the following:

1. create a Python `virtualenv`, be sure to use the `--no-site-packages` option
2. `source /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate`
3. install `rosdep` using `pip`: `pip install rosdep`
4. `sudo rm -rf /etc/ros/rosdep`
5. `sudo rosdep init`

..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
.. then finally a `rosdep update`. If that does succeed, it could be that some Python library has been updated on your system that is interfering (somehow) with `rosdep`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
Also check your `PYTHONPATH`, and whether your setting it explicitly in your `.bashrc` (fi).

Note that we're just checking everything, as without being able to reproduce your issue, it's hard to diagnose.

**Comment by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on 2018-03-08**:
PYTHONPATH in the machine I have been given is empty.
In the machine kinetic works is set to:
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Could this be the problem?
Installation from my side has been identical concerning ROS. But the machine had previous SW installed..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
`PYTHONPATH` pointing to `/opt/ros/..` probably means that the machine you're checking against does a `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` in its `.bashrc`. That should not matter.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-08**:
Check whether you have Python pkgs installed through `pip`:

```
find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages -maxdepth 2 -name __init__.py | xargs realpath | LANG= xargs dpkg -S 2>&1 | grep 'no path found' | sed "s/.*\/\([^\/]*\)\/__init__\.py.*/\1/"
```

these may be interfering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Problem solved. In the machine where I was trying to install Kinectic, at the end of the .bashrc file, there were the following lines:

```
export http_proxy=''
export https_proxy=''
export ftp_proxy=''
export socks_proxy=''
```

which were making rosdep fail. After commenting these lines, installation has gone ok as always.
Thanks a lot for the fast received help.

---

Originally posted by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) with karma: 149 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-09**:\

> - are you behind a (company) firewall or proxy server?

so it was a proxy after all :)

The `no host specified` error could then have come from `urllib(2)` complaining that `*_proxy` variables were set, but did not specify "a host".